# PHP - Delete all items from an array after item with defined value

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I'm trying to remove all items from an array that have a certain value but only if that certain value occurs in the array. For example:

```
$breakers = ('a','b','c');
$array1 = ('z','z','a','b','c','z','z''z');
$array2 = ('z','b','z','z','z''z');
$array3 = ('z','c','z','a','z','z');
$array4 = ('z','z','z');
```

I want to remove all  occurrences of 'z' after the last instance  of 'a','b' or 'c' but only when 'a','b' or 'c' occur in the array so the output would be:

```
$array1 = ('z','z','a','b','c');
$array2 = ('z','b');
$array3 = ('z','c','z','a');
$array4 = ('z','z','z');
```

I've got as far as being able to check if $breakers occurs in the array with (for example):

```
if (count((array_intersect($breakers, $array1)))>0) { ... }
```

But I'm lost with how to then say "Delete all 'z' values that occur after the last occurance of any value in $breakers

Comment: Get the position of the last occurence and then from that point delete till the size of the array is reached. If you want to stop deleting if the value is no z, you would have to check every value after the last occurence and then decide to either delete or keep it.

Comment: Why not using a simple for loop with a counter ? Count +1 when you find an occurance of your breaker, your count will then serves you as an index in your breaker array. Then if your count is higher than the size of your breaker, delete all the next "z"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work

```
<?php
$breakers = ('1','2','3');
$array1 = ('z','z','a','b','c','z','z''z');
$lengthb = count($breakers);
$match = 0;
$count = 0;
flag=0;
foreach($array1 as $val)
{

    if($val == $lenghtb[$match])
    {
        $match++;
     }
    if($match == $lengthb)
    {
        flag = 1;
        break;
    }
$count++;


}

if(flag == 1)
{
array_slice($array1,0,$count+1,true);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

User array_filter with a flag, and you should reset the flag before each filter.

```
<?php
$breakers = array('a','b','c');
$array1 = array('z','z','a','b','c','z','z','z');
$flag = false;
var_dump(array_filter($array1, function($v)use(&$flag, $breakers){
    if($flag)
        return false;
    if(in_array($v, $breakers))
    {
        $flag = true;
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}));
```

the result:

```
ei@localhost:~$ php test.php
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "z"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "z"
}
```